Dynamically sized struct in Arc
I want to create a dynamically sized struct within an Arc, but I can't find a way to do that.
Here's what I'm trying to achieve
struct UnknownSized(usize, [u8]);

fn main() {
    let attached_data: usize = 42;
    let data: Vec<u8> = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; 

    let arc_object = Arc::new(UnknownSized(attached_data, data)); // Did not work
}

I was expecting just a single level of indirection for this object, rather than using something like a box around a [u8] or wrapping another Arc around a [u8]. No referencing a slice either. i want an owned slice in an Arc with usize.
And i want no dependencies either, if possible.

Note nothing here involves tuples, which are fixed-length heterogeneous sequences ((T, U, V) etc.). Slices ([T]) are fixed-length homogeneous sequences.

Can't you get away with  struct UnknownSized(usize, Vec<u8>); ?

@EugeneSh. For context, i am developing a programing language and i am making a object system for my programing language. the usize is a type id of the object and the [u8] is the actual data of an object.  I can't use Vec because it would result in slower access to the objects.

Implementing this by hand is incredibly tricky.  Instead, we can lean on the slice-dst crate to take care of the unsafe heavy lifting for us:
use std::sync::Arc;

use slice_dst::SliceWithHeader;

fn example() -> Arc<SliceWithHeader<usize, u8>> {
    let attached_data: usize = 42;
    let data: Vec<u8> = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    SliceWithHeader::new(attached_data, data)
}

This stores the usize along with the u8 data inline.
In this case the additional data stored with the slice is a single usize, but you can replace usize with a tuple or named struct should you need to store multiple values alongside the u8 data.

I have edited the question. the usize is not storing the length of the slice, it stores a data that i need for my specific purpose. and the reason that i use the word tuple because when defining this type of structure struct UnknownSized(usize, [u8]); it calls struct tuple so i get confused with normal tuples.

I see. Well, if you're actually wanting to do it this way, then it's substantially more complicated because you need to handle allocation yourself, which is non-trivial especially when working with Arc. I think at a minimum you would need the struct to be #[repr(C)] so that you have guarantees about its layout.

@HelloWorld2457 See my updated answer. There is an existing crate that solves this problem.
